# How to fill out all possible columns in a dataframe with r data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, transition

Suppose we start with the below `data` dataframe, generated by the code immediately beneath:

```
> data
  ID Period_1 Period_2 Values State
1  1        1  2020-01      5    X0
2  1        2  2020-02     10    X1
3  1        3  2020-03     15    X0
4  2        1  2020-04      0    X0
5  2        2  2020-05      2    X2
6  2        3  2020-06      4    X0
7  3        1  2020-02      3    X2
8  3        2  2020-03      6    X1
9  3        3  2020-04      9    X0

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Period_2 = c("2020-01","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04","2020-05","2020-06","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04"),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X0","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )
```

I am trying to learn how to use R package data.table, and would like to use it to count transitions out of a given state (state "X0" in the below code example) to another state, when moving or "transitioning" from one period to the next (in this case, period measurement is "Period_1"). I get the following results when running the data.table code immediately beneath:

```
   OutflowState 2 4
1:           X0 0 0
2:           X1 1 0
3:           X2 1 0

Code run:

library(data.table)

dcast(
  setDT(data)[, OutflowState := factor(shift(State, type = c("lead"))), by = ID]
  [, period_factor := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = "Period_1"]
  [, period_factor := as.numeric(period_factor) + 1],
    OutflowState ~ period_factor, length, 
    value.var = "Values", subset = .(State == "X0"), drop = FALSE
)
```

This output is correct, but I would like to (a) add columns to the output for periods 1 and 3 (period 1 will always be all 0's and period 3 should show all 0's in the case of this `data` dataframe because there were no state = X0 in periods 2; and (b) drop from the output the column where Period_1 = 4, because there is no period = 4, it's just a trick used in the code above `as.numeric(period_factor) + 1` in order to flag the next transition period. How could I do this?

I get the following interim dataframe when running the segment of code shown beneath it, so one solution is to knock out any rows where OutflowState = NA (eliminating all notional period 4's) but I don´t know how to do this.

```
   ID Period_1 Period_2 Values State OutflowState period_factor
1:  1        1  2020-01      5    X0           X1             2
2:  1        2  2020-02     10    X1           X0             3
3:  1        3  2020-03     15    X0         <NA>             4
4:  2        1  2020-04      0    X0           X2             2
5:  2        2  2020-05      2    X2           X0             3
6:  2        3  2020-06      4    X0         <NA>             4
7:  3        1  2020-02      3    X2           X1             2
8:  3        2  2020-03      6    X1           X0             3
9:  3        3  2020-04      9    X0         <NA>             4

setDT(data)[, OutflowState := factor(shift(State, type = c("lead"))), by = ID][
  , period_factor := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = "Period_1"][
  , period_factor := as.numeric(period_factor) + 1  
  ]
data
```

This question is an outgrowth of [How to use data.table to build a new dataframe showing inflows into a specified transition state based on the value of an element in a prior row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155945/how-to-use-data-table-to-build-a-new-dataframe-showing-inflows-into-a-specified) addressing transition inflows. Note that the above data.table code allows for the alternatives of defining the time horizon as Period_2 and for summing the transitions of Values rather than counting transitions, and needs to maintain those capabilities.

The image below better illustrates:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take the `state_inflow()` function from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165826/3817004) to the question [How to use data.table to build a new dataframe showing inflows into a specified transition state based on the value of an element in a prior row?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72155945/3817004) and turn it into a `state_outflow()` function:

```
state_inflow <- function(mydat, target_state) {
  dcast(
    setDT(mydat)[, Previous_State := shift(State, fill = target_state), by = ID],
    factor(Previous_State) ~ factor(Period_1), length, value.var = "Values",
    subset = .(State == target_state), drop = FALSE
  )
}
```

by *interchanging the roles* of `State` and `Previous_State` in `dcast()` :

```
state_outflow <- function(mydat, target_state) {
  dcast(
    setDT(mydat)[, Previous_State := shift(State), by = ID],
    factor(State) ~ factor(Period_1), length, value.var = "Values",
    subset = .(Previous_State == target_state), drop = FALSE
  )
}
```

In addition, no fill value is supplied to the `shift()` function. So, the previous state of the first period of each `ID` is `NA`.

Calling the function gives the expected result:

```
state_outflow(data, "X0")
```

> ```
>    State 1 2 3
> 1:    X0 0 0 0
> 2:    X1 0 1 0
> 3:    X2 0 1 0
> ```

There is no need to tweak factor levels.

Answer (score 1):

`dcast` with `drop = FALSE` will create columns for every factor level of `period_factor`, so it you want columns `1` and `3` but not `4` in the result, we need to set the level of `period_factor` to include `1` and `3` but not `4` (and keep it `factor` class!). I've simplified the creation of `period_factor` too, `lapply` and `.SDcols` would only be needed if we were applying this to multiple columns:

```
dcast(
  setDT(data)[, OutflowState := factor(shift(State, type = c("lead"))), by = ID]
  [, period_factor := factor(Period_1 + 1, levels = seq(1, max(Period_1)))],
    OutflowState ~ period_factor, length, 
    value.var = "Values",
    subset = .(State == "X0" ),
    drop = FALSE
)
#    OutflowState 1 2 3
# 1:           X0 0 0 0
# 2:           X1 0 1 0
# 3:           X2 0 1 0
```